# Is it possible to Migrate from BizTalk 2013 R2 to BizTalk 2020 without going through BizTalk 2016?

Tags: migration, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-2020

By migrating from BizTalk 2013 R2 to BizTalk 2020, I mean :

- Take 2013 sources
- Put them into VS 2019
- Upgrade, compile and deploy
- Test each flows

We use the 2013 SQL adapter a lot, so I'll have to modify that as well.
I may have to adapt some transformations as well.

Is it possible to avoid BizTalk 2016 ?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Yes, replacing the SQL adapter with the WCF-SQL adapter is going to be a bit of work, other than that it should be fine

Comment: I was able to upgrade and deploy one flow but I cannot test it due to our infrastructure. It will be so much work just for one test so I was wondering if anyeone has done this succesfully before.

Comment: Give me a month or so. I'll be migrating solutions from both 2010 and 2016 to 2020 soon.  But yes, from 2016 I believe you can just upgrade it by opening it in Visual Studio and recompiling and redeploying.  You will have to regenerate the schemas for the WCF-SQL adapter and remap those.  From 2010 there are a few more gotcha's with some breaking changes in maps.

Comment: @ The close voter.  No, it isn't "About general computing hardware and software", this is specifically about using development tools to upgrade solutions to a new version of BizTalk.

Comment: Note, there is a book coming out soon called Migrating to BizTalk Server 2020 by some well know people in the BizTalk sphere.   https://www.biztalk360.com/ebook/migration-to-biztalk-server-2020/

Comment: Thank you I will check the link for next days. Also Is it possible for you to keep me update when you will be done with your migration please ?

Comment: Link to order it  https://biztalk360.myshopify.com/products/migrating-to-biztalk-server-2020

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe you can just upgrade it by opening it in Visual Studio 2019 + the BizTalk extension and recompiling and redeploying and then testing.

You will have to regenerate the schemas for the WCF-SQL adapter and remap those.

Also check the .Net Version that is being targeted, especially in any helper classes that that don't automatically have their .Net version changed.